# How to speed up startup of nmbd?

Tags: 20.04, samba, services, optimization

I'd like to figure out what is taking `nmbd` so long to start up and fix it.

So how can I speed up the startup time of `nmbd`? Those pesky five seconds look a bit like they could be some timeout of sorts. And since `smbd` depends on `nmbd` this slowdown affects startup of the Samba server.

No matter what I do, it always appears to take almost exactly five seconds to start up, but most importantly by default `nmbd` and `smbd` are in the `systemd-analyze critical-chain` output right before reaching `multi-user.target`.

```
# systemd-analyze blame|grep -P '^\d'
5.963s fwupd.service
5.062s bolt.service
5.043s nmbd.service
1.088s dev-nvme0n1p2.device
1.045s upower.service

# systemctl status nmbd.service 
● nmbd.service - Samba NMB Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nmbd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-06-29 22:32:28 CEST; 6min ago
       Docs: man:nmbd(8)
             man:samba(7)
             man:smb.conf(5)
   Main PID: 1645 (nmbd)
     Status: "nmbd: ready to serve connections..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 76702)
     Memory: 12.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nmbd.service
             └─1645 /usr/sbin/nmbd --foreground --no-process-group

Jun 29 22:32:23 sysname systemd[1]: Starting Samba NMB Daemon...
Jun 29 22:32:28 sysname systemd[1]: Started Samba NMB Daemon.
```

This was *after* I had overridden both the `nmbd.service` and `smbd.service` units as follows:

```
[Unit]
After=multi-user.target

[Install]
WantedBy=
```

... which resulted in this (`systemd-analyze plot` output):

[image: Queuing nmbd after multi-user.target]

... as opposed to this (`systemd-analyze plot` output) *before*:

[image: Preset for nmbd, queued before multi-user.target]

Both boots took twelve seconds plus some.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and decided to go looking through the source code. There is a 5 second gap in the logs before a log message from `../../lib/util/become_daemon.c:135(become_ready)`. By searching in the [source code](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba) for `become_ready`, I found the [`nmbd.c` source code](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/blob/master/source3/nmbd/nmbd.c). Now, what might cause a delay of five seconds but a `sleep()` call? And, sure enough, on [line 371](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/blob/master/source3/nmbd/nmbd.c#L371) there is the following code:

```c
        /* We only count IPv4, non-loopback interfaces here. */
        while (iface_count_v4_nl() == 0) {
            sleep(5);
            load_interfaces();
        }
```

[`iface_count_v4_nl`](https://gitlab.com/samba-team/samba/-/blob/master/source3/lib/interface.c#L140) returns the number of interfaces whose IP is **not** loopback and **is** IPv4. This suggests that scheduling nmbd.service to start *after* `network-online.target` should work.